# Different answers when trying to reverse-engineer an integral

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

So I was trying to find the indefinite integral $\int sin^2(x)dx$ by reverse engineering it, i.e by finding a suitable polynomial which can be differentiated to find the original integral.

$I = \int sin^2(x)dx \\
D = {d\over dx}sin^3x = {d(sin^3x)\over dsin(x)}* {d(sinx)\over x} * {d(x)\over dx} \text{[Using Chain Rule]}\\
=> D = 3sin^2x*cosx*1
=> D = 3sin^2x.cosx\\
=> {d\over dx}({sin^3x\over 3cosx}) = sin^2x \text{  (... 1)}\\
\int {1\over3cosx}dx = \frac 13 * \int secx dx = {\ln(|tanx+secx|)\over 3}
=> {1\over 3cosx} = {\ln(|tanx+secx|)\over 3}dx\\
\text{Substituting this value in ...1,}\\
{d\over dx}{sin^3x*\ln(|tanx+secx|)\over 3} = sin^2x \\
=> \int  {d\over dx}{sin^3x*\ln(|tanx+secx|)\over 3} = \int sin^2x\\
=> I = {sin^3x*\ln(|tanx+secx|)\over 3} + C
$

On using Calculators online, the answer comes up to be $$ {\frac 12}(x-{sin2x\over2})+C$$
The answers may come back different but the area under the graph should be constant, so I tried to put $x = \pi$ in both equations and omitted the arbitrary constant.
On putting these in a scientific calculator, two different values are obtained.
According to the online formula, the Area under Graph = ~1.54

Meanwhile, using the formula I obtained, Area under Graph = ~$3*10^-6$

Did I do any step wrong, and if so, what would be the correct formula using this method?

Comment: In addition to the incorrect integration, note that two different answers for the same indefinite integral don't necessarily have the same constant $C$. So ignoring the "$+C$" and evaluating both at a specific $x$ value could give different answers even if both are antiderivatives.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$
\frac{d}{dx}(\sin^3 (x)) = 3 \sin^2 (x) \cos (x) 
$$
does not imply
$$
\frac{d}{dx} \left( \frac{\sin^3 (x)}{3 \cos(x)} \right) = \sin^2 (x).
$$
This is where you went wrong. You can't put the $\cos(x)$ inside the derivative like that. You can only say that
$$
\frac{1}{\cos(x)}\frac{d}{dx} \left( \frac{\sin^3 (x)}{3} \right) = \sin^2 (x),
$$
as long as $\cos(x) \neq 0 $.

Comment: I did not say  $$\frac{d}{dx} \left( \frac{\sin^3 (x)}{3 \cos(x)} \right) = \sin^2 (x).$$
I said $$\frac{d}{dx} \left( \frac{\sin^3 (x)}{\int3 \cos(x)dx} \right) = \sin^2 (x).$$

Comment: That statement is not correct either - $d/dx$ does not distribute across fractions like that, see the [quotient rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotient_rule).

Answer (score 0):

Cos(2x) = Cos²x-Sin²x = 1-2Sin²x.

Sin²x = (1-Cos(2x))/2.

After substituting and solving we get 1/2(x-(Sin(2x))/2).

Hope it helps.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I know how that works, but I wanted to ask if my method of finding the integral is wrong somewhere